# MIGS - Payment gateway Undefined System Error E5028-07150641: Invalid Digital Receipt Delivery URL

Tags: payment, global-payments-api

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SZVz.png)

Global payment (MIGS) given below issues, someone has any idea about this :(